# Identical HTML/CSS looks differently

Tags: html, css, view

I've made two identical pages, one calls another by clicking a link. 
However, my top menubar changes significantly. What could be the reason? 
HTML/CSS are absolutely same

```
<html> <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body> <div class="wrapper">

    <div id="topmenu" class="navigator">
       <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">(logo)</a></li>
            <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li class="search">    
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
            </li>
            <li class="right"><a href="#">Log In/Sign Up</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my CSS I will put to jfiddle not to overload the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/wg54d8az/
I am using same CSS file for both pages.
I've read some guides, however I was not able to fix the problem. HTML validator shown following mistake:
"Line 4, Column 42: Attribute content not allowed on element meta at this point.
"
However, I cant clearly get what the problem is.

Comment: Could you send the links to pages?

Comment: unfortunately, I have it just offline.

Comment: hmmm... I can make rar archive or something

Comment: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/681a20e195d2/mysite.rar  here it is

Answer (score 1):

Well the difference is that on FAQ page your links inside topmenu don't have `font-size:18` like they do on the index page.

The problem is in the meta tag before css link on the FAQ page. Change

```
<meta content="text/html; charset="utf-8">
```

to

```
<meta content="text/html" charset="utf-8" >
```

and then page will properly load index.css

I guess they way you specify page content now it doesn't recognize UTF-8 as encoding format. That leads to problems with above attribute `font-size:18` (notice you only wrote number without measure unit - pixels). Other way to fix your problem is to use:

```
font-size:18px;
```

inside your index.css

Comment: Thank you! I am the very beginner and each string goes so hard for me! I will do it!

Comment: Just don't give up ;)

Comment: I am back. I've attempted everthing you suggested but unfortunately it does not help. Do you have any suggestions what else can I try?

Comment: Ok. I found a solution. I've renamed files and sacrificed a chicken. It works. No ideas how.

Comment: Guess I'm too late to save the chicken. Poor chicken :P